# Am I being Scammed by a Sugar Momma?

Tags: scams, sugar-daddy, money-laundering

Lemme start this off by saying I haven't done anything yet or handed over any info yet, I'm just trying to see in advance whether it's time to block this lady and move on or keep riding the trail.

Met her online from Seeking Arrangements, and most silly sugar babies do, and after talking and forming a connection for a few days, she says she's ready to set me up with an allowance and make me her loyal sugar baby. Had me delete my SA account and everything to prove my loyalty. And now she's saying she also wants me to work in her "store" and also be her "account manager". Still waiting for details on what this store is and what being her "account manager" entails, but so far she's already told me she wants to keep money in my bank account.

Should I just make a brand new and unrelated bank account for my safety? Or should I decline being the Account manager and keep it at the affection level of things? I was also going to be pushing for payment through something secure like PayPal, but is that even safe? Any and all answers appreciated, thanks so much!

*** I will add: She hasn't asked for my banking info or anything yet, nor do I intend to give her any of it. Just wondering if the "Account Manager" part seems fishy, or working in a store, or if these are normal legitimate things

Comment: No, this case is a little different. She hasn't asked for my banking info or anything yet, nor do I intend to give her any of it. Just wondering if the "Account Manager" part seems fishy, or working in a store, or if these are normal legitimate things

Comment: Sigh. Just search on this site for "sugar scam", you'll see there are lots of variations on these scams. You said "She wants to keep money in your bank account". **You** are legally responsible for what happens in your account. At some point she is going to make some sort of bogus deposit into your account. When the bank eventually figures out that it's bogus (which can take a while), **you** will be on the hook for it.

Comment: Sugar momma scam was an issue yesterday, already: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/121338/is-my-sugar-mamma-scamming-me

Comment: Don't forget when you finished reading the answers to report this person to Seeking Arrangements.

Answer (score 10):

> And now she's saying she also wants me to [...] be her "account manager". [...] she's already told me she wants to keep money in my bank account.

You are being recruited as a [money mule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Money_mule). The criminal will send you money from hacked bank accounts to your personal account and then ask you to forward that money. Often in form of hard to trace methods like Western Union, gift cards or physical valuables like phones.

A couple days after you did that, the bank will find out that the original transfer to your account was illegitimate and reverse it. But you won't be able to reverse the method you used to forward those funds. You will have lost that money.

---

In general, keep in mind that there are dating sites for finding a date and job sites for finding a job. If someone you met on a dating site offers you a job, that's just as creepy as if someone contacts you on a job site and asks you to date them. Break contact and report it to the platform.

"Seeking Arrangements" is somewhere in between a dating site and a job site, considering that compensated dating could be seen as a form of sex work. Still, if someone on that site wants you to do anything for money which doesn't involve any of your romantic services, then something is wrong. If they wanted a personal assistant, accountant or salesperson, they would look for one on Indeed.